# Undetected Chromedriver issue when headless is on

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

```py
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(url):
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.title_contains(('Reservations'))
        )
        print(driver.title)
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e).__name__)
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.example.com/')
```

if `headless = True` the site isn't responsive. How can i solve that?

> P.S am seeking solution for selenium only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a virtual display such as Xvfb so that you don't need to use headless mode on a headless machine such as Linux servers.

There's a Selenium Python framework, https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase, with built-in integration to undetected-chromedriver for that exact thing. When running your tests, add `--uc` as a pytest command-line option for your SeleniumBase tests. Eg:

`pytest --uc --xvfb`

That lets you successfully run Selenium Python tests on a Linux headless machine in undetected-chromedriver mode. (With [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase))

You can use the following for your test, `example.py`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_hyatt(self):
        self.open("https://www.example.com/")
        self.assert_in("Reservations", self.get_title())
        print(self.get_title())
```

Then when running it:

```bash
pytest example.py --uc --xvfb
==================== test session starts ====================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: html-2.0.1, xdist-2.5.0, forked-1.4.0, rerunfailures-10.2, ordering-0.6, cov-3.0.0, metadata-2.0.2, seleniumbase-4.3.8
collected 1 item                                                                                   

example.py Example Domain
.

==================== 1 passed in 8.68s
```

Comment: first of all, Thank you. secondly. is `Pytest` and --uc --xvfb must be from the command line ?

Comment: Yes, ``pytest`` is run from the command-line. It comes with several comman-line options, and SeleniumBase adds more options, such as ``--uc`` and ``--xvfb``.

Comment: is that really require a real machine, as am trying to run that over docker right now but looks like the site is not responsive for it.

Comment: It should work in Docker as long as Xfvb is on it and started. In the SeleniumBase [Dockerfile](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/Dockerfile), you'll see the Xvfb install and start commends.

Comment: am not sure if am building the docker correctly, I don't want to be the one which asking a lot. but i really respect your time and wish to see a simple docker file you used that can run that script over docker.

Comment: Use the instructions from this: [integrations/docker/ReadMe.md](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/integrations/docker/ReadMe.md) to do a Docker build on [Dockerfile](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/Dockerfile), but with a few modifications, mainly to [integrations/docker/run_docker_test_in_chrome.sh](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/integrations/docker/run_docker_test_in_chrome.sh) so that you run the test from the example in the solution above with the command-line args ``--uc`` and ``--xvfb``. Modify the example test.

Comment: And you'll need to clone https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase for that.